# SharePoint form not autopopulating, works on InfoPath

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, infopath

I am currently having an issue with my SharePoint form autopopulating a field. During the InfoPath preview, the field autopopulates properly, however it does not work on sharepoint. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by SharePoint form and InfoPath form ?

SharePoint forms don't have built in functionality to autopopulate fields except for the choice field default value.

are you sure you are publishing your Infopath Form into SharePoint ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint OOTB won't auto populate the field, did you have some custom JavaScript code which will populate the control in SharePoint form ?

If yes, please refer the demo below:

[Auto fill fields with Jquery and SPServices](http://AUTO-FILL%20FIELDS%20USING%20JQUERY%20AND%20SPSERVICES)